# What is the best way to manipulate controls that are within a sub-frame? (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm not sure of what is the best approach for manipulating controls that are within a sub-frame of a Page. Look:

```
<Page x:Name="ParentPage">
    <!-- ParentPage contains a button. When the button is clicked I would like to select all the items in a ListView that is in the InnerPage Page. -->
    <Frame x:Name="SubFrame">
        <Page x:Name="InnerPage" />
    </Frame>
</Page>
```

Now InnerPage is actually loaded via C# code because there are actually several different Pages that are loaded into the SubFrame Frame, and so it is hard to do something like the example below. All of the Pages that are loaded into the SubFrame Frame contain the exact same ListView, though.

```
public sealed partial class ParentPage : Page
{
    public ParentPage()
    {
        InnerPage _InnerPage = SubFrame.Content as InnerPage;
        _InnerPage.SelectAllListViewItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: The best is to always bind na object to the properties you want to change. Also give a look at https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear why you use different inner pages with the same ListView in the SubFrame and what the real effect you want to implement. But you can try to add some different pages in your project, then operate the page in the page's code behind, it would be more easily to manage the pages.

In the parent page, you can use the [Frame.Navigate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_) to load your child page.

```
SubFrame.Navigate(typeof(ChildPage));
```